# How to to mass email (500,000) using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services

How or what should I use in rails to mass mail to 500,000 emails? Also how can I format the email so it goes from different IP and from address. I know AWS is an option (and we would like to use it), but a little guidance here will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for rails mailer. AWS is a good option but you will need to build up a good rep with them or contact them to increase your sending limits because 500,000 is a lot.

Comment: Although Sendgrid http://sendgrid.com is good option

Comment: personnaly, I like mailjet: http://www.mailjet.com/